# Imports undefined, but defined after timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, babylonjs

I am trying to import a class from one file to another, but when I do import it, it returns `undefined` for a couple hundred milliseconds, then I get the value that I am looking for:

```js
// commands.js
export class Command {
  // ...
}

// cmds/Help.js
import {Command} from './../commands.js'

console.log(Command)                         // => undefined
setTimeout(() => console.log(Command), 1000) // => [Function: Command]
```

So, of course, when I try to extend the imported class, I get errors saying that undefined in not a constructor. The only solution that I can see is to wrap everything inside the `cmds/` directory with a `setTimeout()`, but that would not be efficient. I have messed around with using `async`/`await` functions and promises, but neither of those solved the issue.

**Edit 1**

I'm trying to post as much of the requested information as I can, but I am away from my computer so I'm posting all that I can for right now.

The code is running on Node 9.5, and is transpiled by Babel `env` set to `"node": "current"`.

As for the code, here is all I can give you right now:

```js
// Directory structure
[src]
|- cmds/
|  |- Help.js
|  |- Gh.js
|  \...
|- commands.js
|- data.js
|- send-msg.js
\... several more js and json files
// commands.js
import {readData, updateUserData} from './data.js'
import {sendMsg} from './send-msg.js'
//import * as cmdList from './cmds/*' // using babel-plugin-wildcard

export class Command {
  constructor (msg) {
    this.id = msg.author.id
    this.msg = msg
  }
  action () {}
  get data () {
   return readData().user[this.id]
  }
  updateUserData (key, val) {
    updateUserData(this.id, key, val)
  }
  sendMsg (data) {
    sendMsg(this.msg, data)
  } 
}
// there is an exported function, but I do not have the contents atm

// cmds/Gh.js
// There are several similar files in cmds/, including this one and the one
// mentioned in the question, Help.js; there are more. They all have
// the same issue, though.
import {Command} from '../commands'

export class Gh extends Command {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg)
    this.desc = 'Returns GitHub repository link and exits'
  }
  action () {
    this.sendMsg('GitHub link: https://github.com/owm111/knife-wife')
  }
}
```

BTW: the GitHub repository above does not have this code in it yet, but everything that is in it is functioning (i.e. not experiencing this issue).

Comment: what environment are you running?

Comment: Try to  use async.!

Comment: is it possible that `Command` has a delayed initializer?

Comment: Can you post the entire code where you are getting the undefined Error. May be some typo could cause that!

Comment: @DanielA.White Node.js 9.5, transpiling with Babel env, set to `"node": "current"` and `wildcard` plugin. I've tested with node 8 and 7 with the same results.

Comment: @Akhilendrayadav I have tried, but failed. Perhaps you could send an example of what I could do?

Comment: @VigneshMurugan Added as much to the post as I can for right now